# creating a graph on matlab - using the graph function

Tags: matlab, graph

I am trying to create a graph in matlab, not a plot of some function but an actual graph with vertex and edges, the thing is that it won't let me create a graph according to the examples.
what am I doing wrong? is there any library I need to install or something?

when I try this code:

```
G1 := Graph([1,a,3], [[1,a],[1,3]]):
Graph::printGraphInformation(G1)
```

its from the documentation, it gives me this error:

> Undefined function 'G1' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Comment: That does appear to be a direct copy of the documentation's examples, so should work. Are you sure `G1` is not a pre-existing variable in your workspace, and that you don't have a function named `G1` on your search path?

Comment: hi and thank you for your comment, `>> G1                               
Undefined function or variable 'G1'.` its really wierd...

Comment: the symbol := should be as =.